# Как уложить спарсеный курс валюты в таблицу по датам в Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

коллеги!
Подскажите, что не так делаю. Задача собирать с сайта курсы валют по дням и укладывать их в аккуратную табличку. Что я делаю:
1. сформировал список ссылок по которым нужно данные собрать
2. с помощью request скачал данные по этим ссылкам, хотя кажется сделал это не правильно, так как вижу данные за текущий месяц
3. дальше перевел их в строковый формат и завис, что делать дальше не знаю.

Код такой:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_list = []
for i in range(1,13):
    url = 'https://www.calc.ru/kotirovka-yevro.html?date=2018-'

    if len(str(i)) == 1:
        url_list.append((url + str(0) + str(i)))
    else:
        url_list.append(url + str(i))

for link in url_list:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.findAll('table', class_='result_table')

for row in table:
    print (row.text)
```

Направьте, что делать дальше, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался уже знакомым вам модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd


def get_xrates(year_from, year_to=None, month_from=1, month_to=None,
               cur='dollar-ssha'):
    url_pat='https://www.calc.ru/kotirovka-{}.html?date={}-{:02}'
    year_to = year_to or year_from
    month_to = month_to or month_from
    dfs = []
    for y in range(year_from, year_to+1):
        for m in range(month_from, month_to+1):
            df = (pd.read_html(url_pat.format(cur, y, m), skiprows=1)[1]
                    .rename(columns={0:'date', 1:'xrate'}))
            df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
            dfs.append(df)
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).sort_values('date')
```

PS советую также добавить различные проверки правильности указанных параметров...

---

Пример:

```
In [179]: eur = get_xrates(year_from=2018, month_from=4, month_to=5, cur='yevro')

In [180]: usd = get_xrates(year_from=2018, month_from=4, month_to=5, cur='dollar-ssha')

In [181]: eur
Out[181]:
         date    xrate
29 2018-04-01  70.5618
28 2018-04-02  70.5618
27 2018-04-03  70.6038
26 2018-04-04  70.9207
25 2018-04-05  70.9580
24 2018-04-06  70.5926
23 2018-04-07  70.7069
..        ...      ...
36 2018-05-12  73.5145
35 2018-05-13  73.5145
34 2018-05-14  73.5145
33 2018-05-15  73.9430
32 2018-05-16  73.8601
31 2018-05-17  73.7796
30 2018-05-18  73.0236

[48 rows x 2 columns]

In [182]: usd
Out[182]:
         date    xrate
29 2018-04-01  57.2649
28 2018-04-02  57.2649
27 2018-04-03  57.2850
26 2018-04-04  57.5375
25 2018-04-05  57.7646
24 2018-04-06  57.5796
23 2018-04-07  57.8332
..        ...      ...
36 2018-05-12  61.7354
35 2018-05-13  61.7354
34 2018-05-14  61.7354
33 2018-05-15  61.7684
32 2018-05-16  61.9164
31 2018-05-17  62.3033
30 2018-05-18  61.8215

[48 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Ух, ты!Круто!@MaxU, спасибо большое!

Comment: @DenisNovik, всегда рад помочь :)